# Unity C# simple JSON to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine

my PHP file generate list of players like this :

```json
["EnzoDeg40","EDeg40","AstroGeek"]
```

I have successfully downloaded the content with Unity Web Request. But I can't seem to find a solution to convert JSON to a simple array.

Comment: You can't find a solution? Do you mean that the serializer in Unity can't deserialize to a string array? Or?

Comment: IMHO, the JSON should be like `{ "someKey": [ "EnzoDeg40", "EDeg40", "AstroGeek" ] }`. Now we can create a class with `"someKey"` as its field and `JsonUtility.FromJson < TheClassCreated > ( jsonString )` will do the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html). Note that "*Unity does not support passing other types directly to the API, such as primitive types or arrays. If you need to convert those, wrap them in a class or struct of some sort.*". You have to do something like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public struct StringArrayWrapper { public string[] items; }

    private Start()
    {
            var arry = JsonUtility.FromJson<StringArrayWrapper>("{\"items\":[\"EnzoDeg40\",\"EDeg40\",\"AstroGeek\"]}")
```

Comment: You can also use SimpleJSON to load the array https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson